# Spaced Out and Obfuscated

Tags: knowledge, crossword-clues, word-game

In this puzzle I took an English phrase, spaced it differently, then replaced the resulting words with synonyms or definitions. This is an example to show you what I mean.

Spaced out and obfuscated:

> that man tape player button self-esteem

Just spaced out:

> he (from "that man")
>   rew (from "tape player button")
>   ego (from "self-esteem")

Answer:

> he rew ego $->$ here we go

Got it? Then all you have to do is apply the same process to the following:

> definite article anime first child mucus coffee container within Scot. Eng. Wal. TCP/IP reply

Comment: Are proper nouns on the table?

Comment: I would guess so, if they're in the puzzle

Comment: @gannolloy proper nouns are definitely on the table.

Comment: Then this would be easier if I watched anime :(

Comment: @gannolloy use Google. That's what I did.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer is

> There is no turning back.

Because

> definite article = **the**
>
>  anime first child = **rei**
>
>  mucus = **snot**
>
>  coffee container = **urn**
>
>  within = **in**
>
>  Scot. Eng. Wal. = **GB**
>
>  TCP/IP reply = **ACK**

Comment: Ah darn, faster than I was. I had gotten through the first 3.

Comment: I was thinking anime and first child were two different clues. Nicely Done