# Spaced Out and Obfuscated 2

Tags: knowledge, crossword-clues, word-game

If you haven't seen it already, my explanation of a spaced out and obfuscated puzzle is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31830/spaced-out-and-obfuscated). I have a sequel. Here is my spaced out and obfuscated version of an English proverb:

> pasture abbreviated thoroughfares help therefore units registered logo finished

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> [Least said soonest mended](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Least+said,+soonest+mended)

Reasoning:

> Pasture -> lea
>  abbreviated thoroughfares -> sts
>  help -> aid
>  therefore -> so
>  units -> ones
>  registered logo -> tm
>  finished -> ended

Comment: That's a new one!