# Spaced Out and Obfuscated: Afterwards Phone Number Abbreviation Heredity Unit Portion

Tags: knowledge, crossword-clues, word-game

This is, I think, the last of the series. The description of how these works is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31830/spaced-out-and-obfuscated). The answer is an English sentence. Enjoy.

> exclamation confined chop enclosed by index

Comment: These are very enjoyable to work on, thanks for making another!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is the answer

> Open the window, Jones!

Because

> exclamation = o!
>   confined = pent
>   chop = hew
>   enclosed by = in
>   index = Dow-Jones

Also, the title is

> The next generation

Because

> afterwards = then
>   phone number abbreviation = ext
>   hereditary unit = gene
>   portion = ration

Comment: Congratulations! I was actually thinking of the index as simply the Dow, but this works too. Well done!