# Science: Spaced Out and Obfuscated

Tags: knowledge, science, word-game

Although very short on time, I wanted to participate in the Fortnightly Challenge so I have recycled a format that I had intended to retire. Hopefully, it has not entirely worn out its welcome.

Following the rules established [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31830/spaced-out-and-obfuscated), I have combined the last names of four famous scientists in a spaced out and obfuscated format. Have fun!

> Lass one willingly type of weasel women's mag attitude present mug

The above was the original version of the problem solved, amazingly, by Gareth McCaughan and dan1111 despite an error on my part. Those wishing to work through it after the fact may prefer the following version:

> Lass one lucky Viking type of weasel women's mag attitude present mug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I got #4, then dan1111 got #3 and #2, and then I got #1. There really needs to be a way to share checkmarks between two people.

It's

> GAL I LEIF ERMINE W TONE IN STEIN

or

> GALILEI FERMI NEWTON EINSTEIN.

Here

> LEIF is an older and rarer variant of LIEF. I originally had LEOF (an older but I think slightly less obscure variant) and GALILEO, but the question asked for surnames.

Comment: Nice!  some more characters.

Comment: What is a LEOF?

Comment: A tick and an apology. I was thinking Galilei (his last name) and I got all dyslexic regarding the name Leif and the noun lief (which of course come from the same root as leof). I hadn't meant to introduce Chaucerian vocabulary. Well done!

Comment: Heh. And I in turn must apologize because it quite slipped my mind that you were looking for surnames and I gave you Galileo's first name. Never mind, it all works out OK overall.

Comment: Dan, LEOF is a variant of LIEF. But actually LEIF is good too (though perhaps a more obscure variant even than LEOF) and I shall amend my answer accordingly. (I hope this comment will make its predecessors not to confusing to others after the change.)

Answer (score 4):

Building on Gareth McCaughan's answer:

willingly

> lief

weasel type

> ermine

women's mag

> W

attitude

> tone

present

> in

mug

> stein

Which gives:

> Fermi Newton Einstein

Comment: Oo, that works.

Comment: Though I'm not wild about that as a synonym for "attitude" and none of the weasel-types I can identify looks like it works as the end of a famous scientist's name. Maybe it's a metaphorical weasel.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan found another magazine that may help...

Comment: Yes! I know who scientist #2 is, then.

Comment: (and it looks like one of my proposals for "willingly" is right)

Comment: (I see you agree :-).)

Comment: ah, got it. Variant spelling.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer (brainstorm):

1. Lass

> Maid, Maiden, Female, Damsel, Miss, Lady

2. One willingly

> Possibly one word, possible two:
>  
>  freely, voluntarily, cheerfully, agreeably, fairly, at will, openly,

3. Type of weasel

> Stoat, Steppe, Least, Polecat, Ferret, Mink.

4. Women's mag

> Presuming it's 'women's magazine'... Too many to list at the moment.

5. Attitude

> bias, mood, sass, opinion, angle, view, belief, stance

6. Present

> Current, modern, ad hoc, being

1. Mug

> Assault, bash, beat, bash.

Conclusion: No idea at the moment